# Keep null values in List when serializing to XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a list that can contain objects of different types and also `null`values. When I serialize the class to XML, I want to keep these `null` values but they get automatically removed. Setting `IsNullable = true` in the `XmlArrayItem attribute` did not change anything.

I have the following simplified structure of classes:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlArray("Items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("TypeA", typeof(A), IsNullable = true)]
    [XmlArrayItem("TypeB", typeof(B), IsNullable = true)]
    public ObservableCollection<Base> MyCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Base
{

}

public class A : Base
{

}

public class B : Base
{

}
```

As said before, `MyCollection` can contain objects of 2 different types but also `null` values (in my example at index 0 and 2).

This is my serialization code:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<Base>
{
    null,
    new A(),
    null,
    new B()
};

var stream = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\test.xml", FileMode.Create);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (MyClass));
serializer.Serialize(stream, myClass);
```

I get the following XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Items>
    <TypeA />
    <TypeB />
  </Items>
</MyClass>
```

How can I keep the null values in the list? I searched for a while but I only found solutions how to remove null-properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, indeed, I haven't succeeded in making working the XmlArrayItem with the IsNullable property but if you don't mind a slightly different XML Output you can try that:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        [XmlArray("Items", IsNullable = true)]
        public ObservableCollection<Base> MyCollection { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(A))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(B))]
    public class Base
    {

    }

    [XmlType("TypeA")]
    public class A : Base
    {

    }

    [XmlType("TypeB")]
    public class B : Base
    {

    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass() { MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<Base> { new A(), null, new B(), null } };
        var wtr = new StreamWriter("C:\\avp\\test.xml");
        var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        s.Serialize(wtr, myClass);
        wtr.Close();
    }
```

Then you'll get that output:

```
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Items>
    <Base xsi:type="TypeA" />  
    <Base xsi:nil="true" />
    <Base xsi:type="TypeB" />
    <Base xsi:nil="true" />
  </Items>
</MyClass>
```